# Passing args to QuickLinksDialog with JS

Tags: 2010, development, javascript, client-object-model, modal-dialog

I have a small button on a site which when i press should start a QuickLinksDialog and fill in some of the fields there.

Everything goes good and well except the fields (like: title and url) still stay empty.

Any idea how can i work this out?

Here is the js function for this:

```
        var args = new Array();
        args[0] = title;
        args[1] = path;
        args[2] = "";
        var features = 'resizable=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,directories=no,location=no,width=850,height=600';
        var redirectUrl = Sanco_GetBaseUrl() + '_layouts/QuickLinksDialog.aspx?Title=' + title + '&URL=' + path;
        if (browseris.ie55up)
            features = 'resizable: no; status: no; scroll: no; help: no; center: yes; dialogWidth: 850px; dialogHeight: 600px;';


        commonShowModalDialog(redirectUrl, features, null, args);
```

Any idea?

BTW also tried like that:

```
   var options = {
        title: "Add to My Links",
        showClose: true,
        allowMaximize: false,
        autoSize: true,
        url: siteURL + '/_layouts/QuickLinksDialog.aspx?Title=' + Title + '&URL=' + URL + '&Source=' + siteURL
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the QuickLinksDialog is but for my custom modals I always use Eric Martin's [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) script. It's quick, easy, and fairly flexible with good documentation.